# Excel Conditional Formatting for multiples of a number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I am trying to do a conditional formatting in excel where if someone types in a number in B1, and if it is not multiples of a number in cell A1, then turn red.

for example if A1 is 5, I want cell B1 to turn red when they type in number which is not multiples of 5, in other words, turn red if cell B1 is not 5,10,15,20,25.......

```
 =and(A1<>B1"",A1<>B1)
```

this is what I have so far, but this would only work if B1 is empty and if B1 is not equal to A1. I can't figure out how to write in formula in such way that it would only become red when it is not multiples of a number.

Please help, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Formula for conditional formatting `=(MOD(B1,A1)<>0)`?

Comment: Thanks, did not know MOD function existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Excel` provides [MOD function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/mod-function-9b6cd169-b6ee-406a-a97b-edf2a9dc24f3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). The syntax is `MOD(number, divisor)`. It returns the remainder of `number / divisor`.

So if `B1` shall turn red when it's value is not a multiple of `A1`, then following formula for conditional formatting in `B1` can be used:

```
=(MOD(B1,A1)<>0)
```

As `MOD(B1,A1)` returns the remainder of `B1/A1`, this is only `0` if `B1` is a multiple of  `A1`. So if it is not equal `0`, then conditional formatting shall be triggered to format cell red.